# How to read multiple files from a directory and append them in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Iam working with files in a folder where i need better way to loop through files and append a column to make master file. For two files i was using reading as two dataframe and appending series. However now i ran into situation with more more than 100 files.
file 1 is as below:

```
Num Department  Product Salesman    Location         rating1
1   Electronics TV      3           Bigmart, Delhi      5
2   Electronics TV      1           Bigmart, Mumbai     4
3   Electronics TV      2           Bigmart, Bihar      3
4   Electronics TV      2           Bigmart, Chandigarh 5
5   Electronics Camera  2           Bigmart, Jharkhand  5

similary file 2:
 Num    Department  Product  Salesman       Location               rating2
  1      Electronics    TV      3           Bigmart, Delhi          2
  2      Electronics    TV      1           Bigmart, Mumbai         4
  3      Electronics    TV      2           Bigmart, Bihar          4
  4      Electronics    TV      2           Bigmart, Chandigarh     5
  5      Electronics    Camera  2           Bigmart, Jharkhand      3
```

What I am trying to achieve is read Rating column from all the other file and append verticaly. Expected:

```
 Num    Department  Product Salesman    Location          rating1   rating2
  1     Electronics TV      3           Bigmart, Delhi      5         2
  2     Electronics TV      1           Bigmart, Mumbai     4         4
  3     Electronics TV      2           Bigmart, Bihar      3         5
  4     Electronics TV      2           Bigmart, Chandigarh 5         5
  5     Electronics Camera  2           Bigmart, Jharkhand  5         3
```

I modified some of the code posted here. Following Code worked:

```
def read_folder(folder):
    files = [i for i in os.listdir(folder) if 'xlsx' in i]
    df = pd.read_excel(folder+'/{}'.format(files[0]))
    for f in files[1:]:
        df2 = pd.read_excel(folder+'/{}'.format(f))
         df = df.merge(df2.iloc[:,5],left_index=True,right_index=True)   
    return df
```

Comment: where `your_directory = glob.glob(f'{your_folder}*.csv')` do this... `df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f).assign(Filename=os.path.basename(f)) for f in your_directory])`

Comment: @DavidErickson Iam trying to append just one column

Answer (score 1):

This method read folder and return all in a pandas dataframe

```
import pandas as pd    
import os
def read_folder(csv_folder)  
   files = os.listdir(csv_folder)
   df = []
   for f in files:
     print(f)
     csv_file = csv_folder + "/" + f
     df.append(pd.read_csv(csv_file))
   df_full = pd.concat(df, ignore_index=True)
   return df, full
```

As I understand your last comment, you need to add rating columns and create one file. After reading all files you can do below operation.

```
final_df = df[0]
i = 1
for d in df[1:]:
    final_df["rating_"+i] = d["rating"]
    i = i+1
```

Comment: code you provided stacks all the file vertically. what iam trying to acheive is append only rating columns vertically.

Comment: I updated it. Your middle explanation was not readable. So I also edited question.

Answer (score 0):

This version of `read_folder()` returns a list of data frames.  It also add a helper column (for ratings).

```
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path

def read_folder(csv_folder):
    ''' Input is a folder with csv files; return list of data frames.'''
    csv_folder = Path(csv_folder).absolute()
    csv_files = [f for f in csv_folder.iterdir() if f.name.endswith('csv')]
    # the assign() method adds a helper column
    dfs = [
        pd.read_csv(csv_file).assign(rating_src = f'rating-{idx}')
        for idx, csv_file in enumerate(csv_files, 1)
    ]
    return dfs
```

Now assemble the data frames into the desired shape:

```
dfs = read_folder(csv_folder)

dfs = (pd.concat((d for d in dfs))
         .set_index(['Num', 'Department', 'Product', 'Salesman', 'Location', 'rating_src'])
         .squeeze()
         .unstack(level='rating_src')
         .reset_index()
)
dfs.columns.name = ''
```

Comment: I modified some of the codes posted here to get like this: